# I want to make the brands scroller to be continuosly without having pause right now it scroll every 1 second

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I have a brands scroller UI element.

I want to make the brands scroller to scroll continuously without having pause. As it stands, it scrolls every second.

Code:

```
  //brands slider
    var $brands = $('.our-brands');
    if ($brands.length){
        $brands.slick({
            dots: false,
            arrows: false,
            infinite: true,
            autoplay: true,
            speed: 1000,
            centerPadding: 10,
            slidesToShow: 8,
            slidesToScroll: 1,
            responsive: [
                {
                    breakpoint: 1025,
                    settings: {
                        slidesToShow: 6,
                        slidesToScroll: 1,
                        infinite: true,
                        dots: true
                    }
                },
                {
                    breakpoint: 900,
                    settings: {
                        slidesToShow: 4,
                        slidesToScroll: 1
                    }
                },
                {
                    breakpoint: 600,
                    settings: {
                        slidesToShow: 2,
                        slidesToScroll: 1
                    }
                }
            ]
        })
    }
```

Comment: Added detail to the question and added js tags

Comment: Doesn't look like the [slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) library supports it. You may want to look for a different solution or write your own